# I need to change the hyperlink attached to the logo on the mobile menu

Tags: menus, logo

I am struggling with this thing for 2 days. I have a hamburger menu and I want to edit the logo which is displaying in there. I could access the content in Appearance > Menus such as custom links and so on but I can't find the logo and where I can edit its hyperlink!

Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, logo come from theme customization or theme customization or theme options.

Comment: the default WP themes and core don't have general hamburger menus and there's no information about how you implemented the hamburger menu or the code. It's not possible to write a generic answer that works for all themes with hamburger menus, can you edit your question to include all the information that might be needed to answer it? Use the edit link under the tags, err on the side of too much information if possible, especially technical information such as PHP code. Is this a feature of a paid theme?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I managed to overcome this problem as follows:

1. Themes > Customize and then I looked up in the headers tab and I saw the header which is used for mobile view.
2. I went to the headers and clicked "edit in Elementor" then I found the hambergur menu there with no access to edit the content but I saw something called "Choose After Items Template" in this section there was a template selected for the content of the menu So **after all I managed to change the logo hyperlink in the template edit in Elementor**.